# STRING_AGG() in one column and distinct values in column next to

Tags: sql, arrays, string, google-bigquery

I am currently using such query to aggregate strings:

```
select
  STRING_AGG(pet_name) over (partition by id, name, second_id, second_name ORDER BY pet_id) pet_names
  id, 
  name, 
  second_id, 
  second_name
 FROM `example`
```

```
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      pet_names      |   id   |        name      |     second_id    |   second_name    |
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   [cat, dog, bird]  |    1   |       anna       |          2       |       rose       |    
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  [cat, bear, tiger] |    2   |       kate       |          3       |       mike       |  
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    [cat, tiger]     |    3   |       john       |          2       |       bate       | 
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

However, I would like to end up with such table (here an example for the first row of the above shown table):

```
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|--------|
|      pet_names      |   id   |        name      |     second_id    |   second_name    |pet_name|
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|--------|
|   [cat, dog, bird]  |    1   |       anna       |          2       |       rose       |   cat  |
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|--------|
|   [cat, dog, bird]  |    1   |       anna       |          2       |       rose       |   dog  | 
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|--------|
|   [cat, dog, bird]  |    1   |       anna       |          2       |       rose       |   bird |
|---------------------|--------|------------------|------------------|------------------|--------|
```

When I try:

```
select
  STRING_AGG(pet_name) over (partition by id, name, second_id, second_name ORDER BY pet_id) pet_names
  id, 
  name, 
  second_id, 
  second_name,
  pet_name
 FROM `example`
```

It doesn't really work properly returning [cat] for `pet_name` "cat", then [cat, dog] for `pet_name` "dog" etc.

Comment: what is your input data?

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant said, please provide some input data. It helps us reproducing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `order by`:

```
select string_agg(pet_name) over (partition by id, name, second_id, second_name) as pet_names,
       . . . 
from `example`
```

The `order by` makes the window function "cumulative" within each group defined by the `partition by` keys.  Without the `order by`, one value is returned for all rows with the same `partition by` keys.